# Add related data with ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Good day,

I am creating an ASP.Net site with MVC 5 and Razor views. I have a Parent class and a Child class, so that a Parent can have multiple Children. I am using EF Code first and have my 2 models with my DB context in the Models folder in my project. I have created scaffolded items for both.

What I have done is on the details of a Parent, I have a list of children, using a _Partial view. What I would like to do is from the Parent details, if you click on a 'New Child' Action Link, the Create for Child is displayed with the ParentId already selected and not editable.

What woukd be the best way to implement this? Would I need to pass the data along to the controller or in ViewBag? I do not know the correct term is for this type of layout/functionality (Master-Detail view?).

I have also been on the ASP.net site, but cannot find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the Parent Id to the Create action using the Action Link. Perhaps something like this, where "item" is the name of the local Parent variable:

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Child", "Create", new { id = item.Id })
```

Your Create action can then pass it along to the form in the Create view.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I actually ended up using RouteValuesDictionary as well as I required some more info passed along as well:
`@{
                            var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
                            routeValues.Add("ParentId", Model.ParentId);
                            routeValues.Add("Surname", Model.Surname);

                        }
                        @Html.ActionLink("New Child", "Create", routeValues)`

Comment: For what it's worth, I think you might be able to put that inline as well, such as: `@Html.ActionLink("New Child", "Create", new { ParentId = Model.ParentId, Surname = Model.Surname });`